# Finding the orthonormal basis of a 3x3 matrix with 2 eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthonormal

I have a quadratic equation of the form: $x_1^2 + 4x_2^2+4x_3^2 + 4x_1x_2 - 4 x_1x_2 - 4x_1x_3 + 2x_2x_3$

My task is to calculate the orthonormal basis for it.

The matrix I made for it: $$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 2 \\
    0 & 4 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 4 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

It has two eigenvalues: $e_1$ = 1 and $e_2$ = 4 (of multiplicity two)

I got only two corresponding eigenvectors (1, 0, 0) and (2, 3, 0), respectively, and then got stuck, because if I understand correctly, it is impossible to get a 2x2 basis for a 3x3 matrix.

What am I missing? I guess I should have two eigenvectors for the eigenvalue of 4, but I triple checked and I am still getting only one.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you specifically asked to find a orthonormal basis of eigenvectors or just an orthonormal basis? With your given matrix the first is impossible.

Comment: Could you please first check your quadratic equation? There is at least 1 typo I guess...

Comment: Your 3x3 matrix is not diagonalizable by similarity and thus not diagonalizable by orthogonal similarity.. The 3x3 matrix is similar to a matrix with diagonal elements 1,4,4 reading down the main diagonal and a 1 on the super-diagonal, i.e. in the 2nd row and 3rd column, the Jordan form of the matrix.

Comment: Of course, a more basic reason why the 3x3 matrix is not orthogonally  diagonalizable is that it is not symmetric.

Comment: @user190080, the quadratic equation is correct, I double-checked. I think I have made a mistake when converting it to the quadratic form

Comment: you have $4x_1x_2-4x_1x_2$ for a starter...also, the matrix doesn't correspond to the quadratic equation